# Adding a new site to CloudFlare

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, multisite

I'm trying to automate my CloudFlare account. For example when I create a new site in multisite wordpress I want to add this new site to my CloudFlare automatically.

I just have a brief insight into CloudFlare API but I haven't found how I could add new sites. But anyway my question would be that do you know any good integration framework between wordpress and cloudflare?
Or at least any other cloudflare tool would be good.

Or if you have any better way of thinking about this problem I'd be very glad to hear about that.

Comment: This seems to be two different questions: how to use the CloudFlare API and asking for a recommendation for a tool to help you integrate CloudFlare with Wordpress. The former is on-topic, but the latter is not so much. You could make this into a better question by focusing on the first part: a question about the CloudFlare API.

Comment: @ColbySkeggs, thank you for your suggestion, I'm going to edit my question, but with the second part, could you please help me which sub-forum would be eligible?

Comment: You might find [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) to be useful, but I am unfamiliar with that site. If you do post something there, make absolutely certain to read [the guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules).

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't been updated in 3 years, but the [TT CloudFlare WPMU Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tt-cloudflare-wpmu-plugin/) still takes good care of this on my site. You could use the plugin or dig in the code to see how it is done.